# How to remove special characters in php

Tags: php, special-characters

Could somebody tell me how to remove special characters from below array in php

```
Array
(
[users] => Array
    (
        [name] => ASSOCIATION OFï¿½CHIEFS OF USERS            
    )
)
```

Output Expected : ASSOCIATION OF CHIEFS OF USERS

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to remove non-ascii characters from a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using [***preg_replace***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function:

```
$arr = ['users' => ['name' => 'ASSOCIATION OFï¿½CHIEFS OF USERS']];
$arr['users']['name'] = preg_replace("/[^\w [:punct:]]+/i", " ", $arr['users']['name']);

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [name] => ASSOCIATION OF CHIEFS OF USERS
        )
)
```

Comment: This is also removing ' character as well

Comment: it does not. `'` is in `[:punct:]` punctuation list. http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str_replace()`

```
echo str_replace ("ï¿½", " ", "ASSOCIATION OFï¿½CHIEFS OF USERS");
```